# Stop a thread from outside while it is waiting for a database query to respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a thread waiting for a database query to respond. The query can take 10+ minutes to run, and sometimes this thread needs to be stopped from the main program, before the query has responded (the query needing to be simply discarded).

```py
def launch_thread(my_sql_query):
    th = threading.Thread(target=run_db_query, args=(my_sql_query,))
    th.start()

def run_db_query(my_sql_query):
    with get_db_connection() as conn:
        result = sql_engine.run(my_sql_query, conn) # can take 10+ minutes to run
    do_something_with(result)
```

The most common way to stop a thread would be to set a flag that the thread listens to and then exits when the flag is raised. However here, the thread is waiting for a database to respond (which can again take 10+ minutes) and as such, there is no way to check for the flag while waiting. The thread needs to be stopped instantly, without waiting for the db to answer.

What's the appropriate way to stop the thread as exposed above (while making sure that the `conn` connection effectively gets closed by the context manager)?

Comment: you can't kill a thread. which sql engine are you using? perhaps there is a way to insert an interrupt there

Comment: This sound like a problem that async solves. Maybe you can use it, idk how tho

Comment: In the end, you'll need to use a DB API that has cancellable queries. Either by interrupting the thread in a blocking scenario, or by using an async API - these usually support cancellation of async tasks

Comment: Just another thing: Why do you think you need to stop the thread at all? If you don't care about the result, discard it, but that doesn't require stopping the thread. If you want to abort the lengthy operation on the DB, then you'll have to signal that to the DB somehow, but stopping the thread won't magically do it either.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the real-life case is slightly more complicated than explained above and the query actually does modify things in the db — which is what I need to cancel in this case